# Fold/unfold div in table?

Tags: php, jquery, html, html-table, fold

A few days ago, I asked a question regarding folding div ([link text][fold-unfold div]). The answers I got allowed me to make good progress in my coding effort. However, my requirements have changed.

Being a newbie with all this web stuff, I though that wrapping the divs with a table and table headers would be easy. Boy, was I wrong.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Animate my Div</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
a            {text-decoration: none; color: black; }
#expand      {background-color: #fff;}
.description {display: none;         }
.entry       {margin: 0; padding: 0px;}
</style>
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".entry a").click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.entry').find('.description').slideToggle(1000);
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("korg", "joe", "bob");
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("wfr11", $con);
$result = mysql_query("
select title,description from webcases");
?>
<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>title</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?><div class="entry"><tr>
<td>
<a href="#expand"><?php echo htmlentities($row['title']); ?></a>
<div class="description"><?php echo htmlentities($row['description']); ?></div>
</td>
</tr></div>
<?php
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, a click on a ticket title does not work. I remove all the code for the table, it works fine: click on a title and the description unfolds

I should be able to fold my div (expand & description) into my table, right? What am I missing?

Comment: ....you can't have a `<div>` there.

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: he means the <div class="entry">.  You can only put content inside of a td or th. you should probably use <td class="entry">

Comment: It's beginning to make more sense. I think I screwed up my nesting...

Comment: I'm not entirely certain as to why you're wrapping this in a table. Wouldn't a simple accordion style system work?  http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion has an example of how to make something hide when the title is clicked.

Comment: @Michard54. I did not jQuery's accordion system. I tested it wrapped with my PHP code and it is working. And my boss likes it. Thanks to all for your time and effort bringing my stupid self out of the darkness into the light.

Answer (score 6):

Chris, have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/neopreneur/kdFHP/

Your HTML needs to look like this:

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="entry">
                <a href="#expand">Title Text (click here)</a>
                <div class="description">Description Text</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```